# Swagger RequestBody annotation "description" not showing on Swagger UI

Tags: java, swagger

I have the following API endpoint code with Swagger annotations (specifically the @Operation annotation with the @RequestBody description string):

```
@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(
          description = "Test String for RequestBody Here"))
```

Full method code:

```
//@ApiOperation(value = CreateOrUpdate.shortDescription, notes = CreateOrUpdate.detail)
  @NewSpan
  @Operation(
      summary = CreateOrUpdate.shortDescription,
      description = CreateOrUpdate.detail,
      requestBody =
      @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(
          description = "Test String for RequestBody Here")) // Swagger
  @PostMapping
  public UserDTO createOrUpdate(@RequestBody UserDTO dto,
                                @ApiParam(value = CreateOrUpdate.apiParamString)
                                @RequestParam(required = false) boolean skipTrainingUser) {
    Result result = userService.createOrUpdateCrmUserObject(dto, skipTrainingUser);
    ...
  }
```

That code results in the following Swagger UI:

[image: Swagger UI without RequestBody description line]

Note that the expected RequestBody description of "Test String for RequestBody Here" is not displayed on the Swagger UI under the *Request body* label.

I'm at a loss to explain why this is happening as it worked just fine in another project.  Any thoughts or ideas will be appreciated.

**Update:** Per Helen's suggestion below I tried putting the Swagger RequestBody annotation before the UserDTO dto in the method statement like this:

```
//@ApiOperation(value = CreateOrUpdate.shortDescription, notes = CreateOrUpdate.detail)
  @NewSpan
  @Operation(
      summary = CreateOrUpdate.shortDescription,
      description = CreateOrUpdate.detail
      )
  @PostMapping
  public UserDTO createOrUpdate(@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(
                                description = "Test String for RequestBody Here") 
                                  @RequestBody UserDTO dto,
                                @Parameter(description = CreateOrUpdate.apiParamString)
//                                @ApiParam(value = CreateOrUpdate.apiParamString)
                                @RequestParam(required = false) boolean skipTrainingUser) {
    Result result = userService.createOrUpdateCrmUserObject(dto, skipTrainingUser);
```

But it still does not display the text on the Swagger UI where it would be expected (under Request body text).

I'm beginning to wonder if there's some strange library conflict going on here.  It works fine either way in a different project/service, but this one has older versions of the Swagger libraries in it...

Comment: Are there any behind-the-scenes code or yaml files that OpenAPI generates that I could look at to see what is "really" going on here?  Just curious - the magic must live somewhere...

Comment: You have `@RequestBody` both before `UserDTO dto` and inside `@Operation`. My guess is they are conflicting. Try using `@RequestBody(description=...)` only before `UserDTO dto` and remove it from `@Operation` and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Helen.  I tried that (see my Update above) and still no joy.  It works both ways (inside the ```@Operation```, or next to the Spring RequestBody annotation) in another Java project...  Of course, I have to leave the Spring RequestBody in there or the endpoint won't work correctly...

Maybe it's a weird library conflict.  This project is older and has older versions of the Swagger libraries imported...

Comment: "[...] but this one has older versions of the Swagger libraries" -- I'd probably try updating to the version(s) that work.

Comment: @DaveNewton - understood.  For a number of reasons I'm not willing to do the refactoring necessary to do that.  There are a LOT of endpoints and I've got a ton of higher-priority tickets to work.  I'll just live with this for now unless Helen has any other ideas.  Thanks all!